# print python dictionary in ruby hash format

Tags: python, ruby, dictionary, hash

I have a simple python dict and it prints in below format,

```
{'stats1': {'var': {'avail': 'yes'}, 'target': {'avail': 'no'}}}
```

But am looking way to print this in below format like ruby hash,

```
{'stats1'=> {'var'=> {'avail'=> 'yes'}, 'target'=> {'avail'=> 'no'}}}
```

I tried Google to get the way to print python dict in ruby hash format but no luck.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: For what it's worth : `{'stats1': {'var': {'avail': 'yes'}, 'target': {'avail': 'no'}}}` is already a valid Ruby hash, with symbols as keys. It's displayed as `{:stats1=>{:var=>{:avail=>"yes"}, :target=>{:avail=>"no"}}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a simple workaround. if `d` is the `dict`

```
print(str(d).replace(': ', '=> '))
```

This works given that there is no `:` anywhere in the strings in the dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

can be done with a recursive scan of the dictionary, checking if value is instance of dictionary to make a recursive call, otherwise just print (escaping of the quote char is also handled)

```
def rp(d,outstream):
    outstream.write("{")
    first_print = True
    for k,v in d.items():
        if not first_print:
            outstream.write(",")
        else:
            first_print = False
        outstream.write("'{}'=> ".format(k.replace("'",r"\'")))
        if isinstance(v,dict):
            rp(v,outstream)
        else:
            outstream.write("'{}'".format(v.replace("'",r"\'")))

    outstream.write("}")
```

testing can be done using `sys.stdout` or `io` to get a `str` object

```
import io

d = {'stats1': {'var': {'avail': 'yes'}, 'target': {'avail': 'no'}}}

outs = io.StringIO()
rp(d,outs)
print(outs.getvalue())
```

result:

```
{'stats1'=> {'target'=> {'avail'=> 'no'},'var'=> {'avail'=> 'yes'}}}
```

Of course this solution is quite frail: passing a list of dicts won't work for instance. Can be done, of course, with more coding and `isinstance`. And there are probably more cornercases.

Comment: This doesn't work if values are not dictionary but list or something else.